# New version upload warning

Tags: android, admob

I am about to update a new version of my app to the Google play store and I am using Google play services for admob. My minsdk is 8. I understand that to use google play service I have to have at least API 9 minimum. However I do have users who are using the app on API 8. In my code I have platform version checks which ensure that on API level 8 not adverts are shown. However, I am getting a warning on Google play:

> You uploaded an APK that uses Google Play services version 8298000. This will only work with Android API levels of 9 and above. It is discouraged to use this Google Play services version unless you have set the minSdkVersion in your manifest to 9 or higher

My app won't crash on API 8 because of the checks in place.

1. Will Google play accept the apk if I ignore the warning?
2. If I change minsdk to 9, what's going to happen to people who were using it on API 8 - will they be able to reinstall it again?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question (2), if you increase the minimum SDK to 9, the update will not be proposed to users having a API 8 device.

Comment: so if the users of API 8 device who purchased the app try to install it what happens ? are they sent the old apk ? or are they denied ?

Comment: They will get the old apk. The new one does apply to them.